# Best place for an R package to write user variables in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-package

I'm in the process of making a package that imports data from a Google API that a user authenticates from within a Shiny app.

I'm modifying a package that uses `httr` for Google verification.  This package keeps a users state in an environment that is sourced at the top of the script:

```
## auth.R in package scripts
.state <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())

a_function <- function(blah){  
  do_stuff
}
```

Is this a good idea for Shiny?  I'm wondering if its ok to set such a variable naked outside a package function.

However, when I try to declare the `.state` environment within a function, the Shiny app can't find it.  I also tried putting it in an `.onLoad` function but that also was not available to Shiny.

Is it ok to leave it as is at the top of a script in the package, or is there a 'better' way that Shiny can see?

Comment: I don't know if this is necessarily a better way, but you could put the server and ui in a [shinyApp]{http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/shinyApp.html} call within a function that you call to start up the shiny app, and have the necessary code before that. So the format would be like                         `x <- function() {                                                                                a_function <- function(blah){ do_stuff() } shinyApp(ui=fluidPage...,server=function....)}`

Comment: Thanks Eugene, thats actually how I have it set up in my test script.  As its a package though, I don't want to have to restrict users to just using shinyApp() if they don't want to.

Comment: Do you know about "global.R"? Any functions/variables you place in that file are visible by both the ui and server

Comment: Hi daattali - yes if I'm making a Shiny script thats fine but I need a location within an R package